# Windows phone xna swipe

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, swipe

I'm making a game and I have a problem:

I want to control the hero in my game through swipes.  For example:

- Swipe to the left : Hero goes to the left
- Swipe up          : Hero jumps

My question is how to check what side a user swipes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this i have checked that on which side a user has touched the screen according to player and then have given the velocity to the player in that side and similarly if user touches above the player then player jumps...  this is not exactly what you need but think you can take some idea how to do your thing....

```
            TouchCollection touchcollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
            foreach (TouchLocation t1 in touchcollection)
            {
                if (t1.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
                {
                    Vector2 touchposition = t1.Position;
                    if (touchposition.X >= (position.X + texture.Width))
                        velocity.X = 3f;
                    else if (touchposition.X <= position.X)
                        velocity.X = -3f;
                    else
                        velocity.X = 0;

                    if (touchposition.Y < position.Y && hasjumped == false)
                    {
                        position.Y -= 10f;
                        velocity.Y = -5f;
                        hasjumped = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (hasjumped == true)
            {
                velocity.Y += 1.5f;
            }
            if (position.Y + texture.Height > 790)
                hasjumped = false;

            if (hasjumped == false)
                velocity.Y = 0;

            position += velocity;
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple article on [Touch gestures on Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/12/touch-gestures-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) is exactly what you need.